# How can I fire a trigger BEFORE a delete in T-SQL 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How can I fire a trigger BEFORE a delete in T-SQL 2005?
The FOR actually fires AFTER an event and they seems no BEFORE argument in the TRIGGER function.
The INSTEAD OF is not what I want. 
I need to fire before I delete a record.
Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you Tom, Mitch and Steven

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the INSTEAD OF option, just explicitly delete the rows at the end. For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.My_Table_Delete_Instead_Of_Trigger
ON dbo.My_Table
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN

     -- Do some stuff here

     DELETE T
     FROM DELETED D
     INNER JOIN dbo.My_Table T ON T.PK_1 = D.PK_1 AND T.PK_2 = D.PK_2
END
```

This assumed a primary key made up of columns PK_1 and PK_2.

Comment: Wouldn't this just fire the trigger all over again?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. But you can perform a rollback in an AFTER DELETE trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  What you can do is check the DELETE table and undo the delete if you need to do so.

Here's the Sequence of events:

- Send DELETE Command to SQL Server
- Item is removed from the table
- OnDelete Trigger Fires Perform your
- Logic If Logic fails/passes/whatever, undo delete

Comment: This doesn't help with the most common use case for a "before delete" trigger - cascading deletes - which leaves me puzzled as to what you *would* do with on-delete.

Comment: I typically use the OnDelete trigger to create a history entry that an element was deleted by a user at a given time.

Comment: Custom auditing that doesn't rely on application behaviour. I like it. +1 for damn good idea.