# Delete trigger SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a rather simple question.
I need to create the delete trigger.

I have three table, Main and T1 and T2. The T1 and T2 are connecting to Main with the same ID field so I already have insert trigger that works great but I need delete trigger which will delete record in T1 and T2 when deleted from the Main table.

Any help?

Comment: Have you considered a foreign key with "ON DELETE CASCADE"?

Comment: yes, and I removed the Enforce foreigh key contrains and I removed check exsisting data..

Comment: @Tony: why remove "check existing data"? This is unrelated to CASCADE DELETE

Comment: Yes, you are right.....but it does not delete if I do not have Enforce to YES

Comment: And my foreign key is in the Main table other T1 and T2 are primary keys

Answer (score 0):

A delete trigger would fire after the DELETE runs. However, the DELETE will fail because of foreign key errors (you have FKs, right?).

Options:

- Stored procedure to delete T2, T1 then Main in a transaction
- Set the FKs to have [cascading delete](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user:27535%20%2bcascade%20%2bdelete)
- Instead of trigger (which fires before the delete) which is effectively like a stored procedure

Comment: Hi I tried the cascade fnction but It will not allow it since it is the same id from two tables, it is not unique

Comment: Tony: don't understand what you mean: if the parent row is not unique how do you know which row to delete?

Comment: All three tables have same ID, that is why I was not able to use the cascade, Connection: Main to T1 and Main to T2, same field

Comment: So, the FK from T2 to Main has delete cascade set. And the FK from T1 to Main has cascade set. Still not sure why you can't do it.

Comment: Sorry guys maybe I am explaining it in a wrong way. Main-id to T1-t1id, Main-id to T2-t2id. Of course they are not the same data but connecting to the same ID field in the Main table, I have to have all the fields from T1 and T2 in the Main updated and deleted.

Comment: You can fire a trigger before the delete, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516119/how-can-i-fire-a-trigger-before-a-delete-in-t-sql-2005

Comment: I tried few more times with different options and If I remove the INSERT triggers it will not insert into Main tbl and my delete trigger is like this:                                               ALTER trigger [dbo].[trigger] on [dbo].[T1]
for  delete 
as 
delete dbo.Main 
select ID from deleted