# Delete trigger not being executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

I have a table `Absence` with an PK `AbscenceId` (yes spelling mistake). I have another table `Note`, with an FK into `Absence` called `AbsenceId` (spelled correct this time). The FK constraint is:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Note]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Note_Absence] FOREIGN KEY([AbsenceId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Absence] ([AbscenceId])
GO
```

When an `Absence` is deleted, I want all `Notes` to go with it. I couldn't do this with `CASCADES`, because a `Note` can belong to something else as well.

So I created a trigger to delete the notes when an Absence is deleted:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_OnAbsenceDelete] ON [dbo].[Absence]
    FOR DELETE AS

    DELETE FROM [Note]
        WHERE AbsenceId IN ( SELECT AbscenceId FROM Deleted )
```

But when I delete an `Absence` that has a `Note` attached to it, I get:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Note_Absence". The conflict occurred in database "ReturnToWork", table "dbo.Note", column 'AbsenceId'.
The statement has been terminated.�
```

It is almost like the trigger is not getting executed?

Comment: Have you tried using an INSTEAD-OF trigger? You would have to also delete the record(s) that was/were originally being deleted. You couldn't use it if your FK already has a delete action though.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory, isn't it? You can't just delete the row from `Note`, you also have to clean up any rows in other tables that reference it.

Comment: I fully understood the error, I guess I just assumed trigger executed before not after, and wasn't sure if trigger was even being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trigger needs to be written as an INSTEAD OF trigger, deleting first from Note and then from Absence.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_OnAbsenceDelete] ON [dbo].[Absence]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE AS
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM n
        FROM deleted d
            INNER JOIN Note n
                ON d.AbscenceId = n.AbsenceId

    DELETE FROM a
        FROM deleted d
            INNER JOIN Absence a
                ON d.AbscenceId = a.AbscenceId
END
```

Comment: If anything fails will I get a full rollback then?

Comment: I wrote a ruby script to do this automatically based on FK constraints. Works great, maybe others can find it useful too. I posted it [here](http://educatedsquirrel.com/2012/07/18/automatically-create-a-cascading-delete-via-triggers/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you try to delete record from absence it fails because of the reference constraint. If the delete is success then your delete trigger will be called.

Also as suggested in this link you can try the instead of [How can I fire a trigger BEFORE a delete in T-SQL 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516119/how-can-i-fire-a-trigger-before-a-delete-in-t-sql-2005)